# Homescreen icon disappears on application update

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I'm facing an unusual scenario with a few of my installed applications.

Whenever there is an update to the application, when I allow Google Play to perform the update, the shortcut that I had on my homescreen gets removed.

What is going on here? Is there something that the app developer has (or hasn't) done that could cause this to happen? This doesn't happen for any of the other shortcuts I have on my homescreen.

It's generally only an annoyance, since I can just grab the app icon from the app drawer and drop it on the homescreen again, but I have to do so after ever update. And I need to notice that it's gone.

Is there anything I can do to keep it from happening?

Further notes:

- Android 4.4 (Moto X), unrooted
- Apps only ever installed from the Google Play Store, with a single Google Account
- The two apps I'm thinking of where this happens are paid apps, but it's not happening with all of the apps I've paid for

Comment: I won't submit as an answer because I can't give you a detailed response but I think its to do with the package and/or name. Android is looking for a specific app/package name for the shortcut.
Think of it as a shortcut within Windows to an app called `myappV1.exe` but then changing the app name to `myappV2.exe` without updating the shortcut. Difference is Android removes shortcuts that point to nowhere, Windows does not.

Comment: But the package name is the same for all versions of an app. That's what makes them the same app.

Comment: Is the issue still relevant, and can you share the name of those two apps?

Comment: I've seen this same behavior on many, but not all, apps, and it doesn't seem to be specific to any one version of Android, nor particular hardware. I did notice, today, on my tablet running Lollipop and using the Google Now launcher, that my Facebook app had a slight variation on this - the icon was not removed from my home screen, but the color was partially desaturated; it's missing from my app drawer, tapping the home screen icon produces the toast "App not found", but I can launch it via Recent Apps, or from its "Launch by main activity" button in System Settings > Apps > Facebook.